# Wordpress - вывод активных евентов по дополнительному полю Дата

Tags: wordpress

У каждого поста есть два дополнительных поля:

> Data_START

---

> Data_END

Формат полей:

> 2018-02-20

Есть код, который сортирует дополнительные поля по полую `Data_END`

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse183601_filter_category_query' );
    function wpse183601_filter_category_query( $query ) {
        // only modify front-end category archive pages
        if( is_category() && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page','6' );
            $query->set( 'orderby','meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key','Data_END' );
            $query->set( 'order','DESC' );
        }
    }
```

Посты выводятся с наибольшим значением `Data_END` поля и по убыванию.

**Пример:**

> 2018-01-16 - 2018-02-28
>
> 2018-02-17 - 2018-02-27
>
> 2018-02-18 - 2018-02-26

Все бы хорошо, только мне нужна сортировка в обратном порядке !

А именно с **меньшего** `Data_END` к **большему**.

> 2018-02-18 - 2018-02-26
>
> 2018-02-17 - 2018-02-27
>
> 2018-01-16 - 2018-02-28

Это можно решить, изменив **order** `DESC` на `ASC`!

Но, тогда нужный мне порядок, уходит в самый конец страниц (pagination).

А он мне нужен в начале !

Вопрос, как это сделать ?

П.с все это нужно для того чтобы пользователи сначала видели евенты которые у которы сначала короткая дата (пример 2018-02-20 - 2018-02-23) т.е евент будет идти ТРИ дня ! значит его на первое место ! А второй который ВОСЕМЬ дней (2018-02-20 - 2018-02-28) будет идти на втором.

Comment: WP_Query по метаполю

Comment: Выше дали исчерпывающий ответ. Если хотите ответ в коде - приведите в вопросе свой код.

Comment: Дело в том, что никакого особого кода нет, в category.php выводятся посты стандартной функцией, а в ней доп поля фун. get_post_meta. Тут как я понял, нужно ДО исполнение вот этой функции <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> сформировать WP QUERY (Дело в том что нужно сравнивать ДАТУ которая уже есть в доп. поле, т.е её нужно как-то получить ДО функции выведение постов.

Comment: Не все так просто, а все потому что есть это один тип поля post, в котором есть НЕТ поле ДАТА, Есть поле ДАТА и есть поле ДАТА и ОКОНЧАНИЕ. Т.е из этих всех данных нужно мастерить логику вывода.

Comment: Все как раз просто. Читайте kama WP_Query

Comment: Не просто, чтобы не трогать запрос внутри страницы category.php нашел способ использовать сортировку в function.php  (pre_get_posts) разбираюсь.  Мне просто нужно сделать логику, если ДАТА есть, сверяем с текущей, если ОКОНЧАНИЕ есть сверяем с текущим, если ДАТА нет, выводим в самом конце. Т.е мне нужно сверять два основных поля это ДАТА и ОКОНЧАНИЕ, ибо есть поле просто с одной ДАТА (т.е евент только в этот день) а есть евенты С и ПО. Там тогда два поля ДАТА и ОКОНЧАНИЕ.. в общем разбираюсь думаю просто но не тут то было )

Comment: Можно и главный запрос модифицировать через pre_get_posts. А можно и свой WP_Query сделать в шаблоне category.php. Так проще. Я бы так и делал. И как в том анекдоте - не до и не после `have_posts while the_post`, а ВМЕСТО))

Comment: Проблему с Pagination решил, pre_get_posts !  в function.php, wp_query использовать не буду, так как он нарушет всю структуру PAGINATION разбиратся некогда почему, страницы показыает одинаковые данные, и т д и т п. Но ! возникла еще одна проблема ! Это логика выводи и сортировки этих самых дат. Т.е какие посты за какими будут выводится по убыванию ! Т.е как их сопоставить вместе ?

Comment: Обновил топик, добавил SQL запрос (meta_query) ибо с запросом будет легче разобраться, а потом уже по нему можно будет составить тот самый meta_query (правильный). Запрос выводит то что нужно в нужном порядке, но не выводит посты где НЕТ доп полей, или Дата уже истекла т.е больше текущей.

Comment: @KAGGDesign я обновил топик еще раз, привел уже проще не куда пример, надесь мы найдем решение данной задачи. Опыт я конечно сегодня получил не плохой, провозившись с этиме wp - meta - query... )